# Not able to download magento2.4.6-p2

Tags: magento2

```
Using = php8.1
composer version = 2.2
In side auth.json updated repo.magento.com public/private key
and all PHP package which is dependant with this version.
still greeting this issue.
**Guide me on this please**
```

[image]

auth.json

```
{
"bitbucket-oauth": {},
"github-oauth": {},
"gitlab-oauth": {},
"gitlab-token": {},
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
        "username": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "password": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    }
},
"bearer": {}
}
```

Comment: What is your auth.json content? Please modify the `username` and `password` values to something like `aaaaaaaaaaa` for security purposes.

Comment: @TuVan auth.json above find please

Comment: your `auth.json` file content seems to be correct. I have provided an answer, please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following command to get the path of the composer's global directory.

```
composer config --list --global | grep 'home'
```

Ensure that your `auth.json` file is located in the same directory as the previous command's output. If it matches, there may be some unusual characters in your `auth.json` file. Try setting the composer auth configuration using the following command:

```
composer global config http-basic.repo.magento.com <public_key> <private_key>
```

In addition, you should use a later version of Composer 2.2, such as 2.2.21, as earlier versions of Composer 2.2 may have compatibility issues with Magento 2. To downgrade/upgrade to Composer version 2.2.1, run the following command:

```
composer self-update 2.2.21
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's working perfect. Great man :)

Comment: I'm glad to help. Cheers!